# Calculate Attempts per second

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate requests per second in python, if someone could help that would be much appreciated, here is what i tried but is not working.

```
i = 0
attempts = 0
before = 0

def rs():
    global attempts
    global before
    before = attempts
    sleep(1)
    rs = attempts - before
    while i < 5:
        attempts += 1
        print(f"Attempts {attempts} | RS {rs}", end="\r")
rs()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get anything rate-related to time, you'll need to keep track of time. You can do that as simply as

```
import time

start = time.time()
do_time_taking_task()
stop = time.time()
duration_in_sec = stop - start
```

I would take the start time immediately before sending any requests, and take the stop time immediately after sending the final requests (no `print()` statements or other logic between final request and `stop = time.time()` that way you don't get bad measurements). From there, "requests per second" is as easy as `requests_per_sec = total_number_of_requests / (stop - start)`